# quartz cron trigger first fire time

Tags: quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

Is  there any way setting crontrigger to begin after a specific date .That is crontrigger going to fire after a specific date using its cron expression.I try using crontrigger starttime and firstfire time but not worked.I can do this with using another trigger but i think there should be another way.

this is cron expression

```
0  0/5  *  * * ?
```

i.e. at minutes (5,10,15,...00) not at now+5

this is log  program writes

Trigger should start at Fri May 27 21:03:31 EEST 2011   // i expect it run on this time

```
Job start at  Fri May 27 20:55:00 EEST 2011          //it ignore start time 
Job start at  Fri May 27 21:00:00 EEST 2011
Job start at  Fri May 27 21:05:00 EEST 2011
```

---

```
 public CronTrigger scheduleJob(RemoteJob job, String cronExpression,Date firstFireTime) throws SchedulerException, ParseException {
    JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(job.getDescription(), job.getName(), job.getClass());
    CronTrigger crTrigger = new CronTrigger(
            "cronTrigger", job.getName(), cronExpression);       
    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, crTrigger);    

    try{
        Calendar  c=Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
        firstFireTime=c.getTime();
        FileWriter writer=new FileWriter("/opt/scheduler.cron",true);
        writer.write("Trigger should start at " +c.getTime().toString()+"\n\n");
        writer.close();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
     crTrigger.setStartTime(firstFireTime);
    crTrigger.setMisfireInstruction(CronTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING);

    return crTrigger;

}
```

this is job executed by trigger .

```
public class ExternalJob extends RemoteJob {

    private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(ExternalJob.class.getName());
    private static ExternalStorageProcessor processor = new ExternalStorageProcessor();
    private ExternalTask task;
    private static final String tempPath = "/opt/itaptemp/";
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private static final long MARK=1L;

    public ExternalJob(String name, String description) {



    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {


         try{
            Calendar  c=Calendar.getInstance();          

            FileWriter writer=new FileWriter("/opt/scheduler.cron",true);
            writer.write("Job start at  " +c.getTime().toString()+"\n");
            writer.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the startTime property to the future Date at which you want the schedule (expression) to start applying.

I see you say that you tried that and it didn't work, but it certainly should, so please try again.

```
    CronTrigger ct = new CronTrigger("foo", "goo", "0 0/10 * * * ?"); // fire every ten minutes, all day every day

    // construct a date of March 17, 2012 10:03:00
    Calendar futureDate = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    futureDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
    futureDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, GregorianCalendar.MARCH);
    futureDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17);
    futureDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    futureDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 3);
    futureDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    futureDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    // use the date as the startTime
    ct.setStartTime(futureDate.getTime());

    // check what time the trigger will first fire
    List fireTimes = TriggerUtils.computeFireTimes(ct, null, 1);
    Date firstFireTime = (Date) fireTimes.iterator().next();

    System.out.println("First fire time: " + firstFireTime);
```

This results in:

> First fire time: Sat Mar 17 10:10:00 MDT 2012

Comment: are you sure this is the case for cron trigger

Comment: Absolutely (unless there's a never-before-reported bug).

Comment: I add my debug info and code .Cron trigger ignoring starttime.

Comment: I see in your example you are setting the startTime property on the trigger AFTER you are storing (scheduling) the trigger.  That's your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using a cron which fires a every even minute beginng a 0 minute (**0**  0/5  *  * * ? ).

You should set the start date alse to even minutes. Therefore you can use `DateBuilder.EvenMinuteDateBefore(StartTime).`

So if your startime was... `Fri May 27 20:55:31` ... the method `DateBuilder.EvenMinuteDateBefore(StartTime)` will convert it to ...
`Fri May 27 20:55:00`.

Then your schedule will look like:

```
Job start at  Fri May 27 20:55:00 EEST 2011
Job start at  Fri May 27 21:00:00 EEST 2011
Job start at  Fri May 27 21:05:00 EEST 2011
```